# Combobox values appearing as single string characters

Tags: python, tkinter

I am utilizing python/tkinter in order to create an electronic form to gather issues from manufacturing floor.

I have a (2) comboboxes.

The 1st combobox gains its "values" from a given dictionary.keys() which updates the "values" of a 2nd combobox. However, when selecting the values for the 2nd combobox after selecting for the 1st combobox, the values only show singular characters from the dictionary.values().

Here is the list from the txt file. The first item on each line is the key, while the rest of the items on the same line are its values.

```
Bondshop, Plies: Layup Difficulty, Plies: Cutting Edge
IB Postbond, POU, Equipment, Inspection, Available Work Space, Big Paint, 1575, QN
General Postbond, Inspection
Seal Area, Inspection
Big Paint, Inspection
Deflash, Inspection
```

Why does my 2nd combobox appear as so? See below.

[image: "...show singular characters"...]

```
    ===snip===

        def loadcategory(self):
        
             # Reads production areas & cateogries from dictCategory.txt file
             self.textfileCategory = open('dictCategory.txt', 'r')
             self.lines_category = self.textfileCategory.readlines()
             for line in self.lines_category:
                 splitLine = line.split(',')
                 dict_category[str(splitLine[0])] = ",".join(splitLine[1:])
             self.textfileCategory.close()

    ===snip===  

        def UpdateData(self, event):
        
            # Updates Category Combobox based on Production Area selection
            self.menu_category.set('---')
            category = self.menu_production_area.get()
            self.menu_category['values'] = sorted(dict_category[category])
    
    ===snip===

        self.menu_production_area = ttk.Combobox(Main_Frame, state='readonly', values = sorted(list(dict_category.keys())), width=25)
        self.menu_production_area.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.UpdateData)
        self.menu_production_area.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='w')
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  'Complete' means that the toy data needed is in the code, not in a file that only you can see.  In other words, replace `load_category` with `dict_category` in the text.  You may discover that the problem is with the file or how load_category converts it.

Comment: My best guess, without seeing your data and code, is that your `line.split(',')` command isn't working as expected so that you're pulling the first character of a string and not the first element of a list when you create `dict_category`'s keys.